# Linq Left Join table with sub set of another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Consider the query

```
var query = from A in _context.A.AsExpandable().Where(condition)
                      let B = _context.B
                      .Where(a=> a.Id == B.Id)
                      .Select(x=> new
                      {
                          x.Id,
                          x.Name
                      }).ToList()
                      select new {A.Id, B }


var res = query.ToList()
```

The Generated T-SQL similar to

```
SELECT [t0].Id, [s].Id, [s].Name
FROM A AS[t0]
LEFT JOIN [B] AS [s] ON [t0].[Id] = [s].[Id]
```

I Was wondering instead of joining the whole table is possible/better to join a subset(may be a inner join which just fetches two column instead of all the columns) of the table to improve performance?.

What it basically does it Left joins table A with table B, I'm trying to join the table A with the subset of table B (Id, Name) instead of selecting all the column.

1. Is it possible to achieve this??
2. would it improve the performance or degrade the performance?

Comment: Why not just a `join` (based on `a.Id == b.Id`) and a `select`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I tried using joins too, but i didnt get the expected T-SQL statement I was hoping for, since i was facing performance issues I was trying out different techniques tbh i have no idea or some of the methods I'm using but it kinda did tune my performance up. right now I'm just wondering is it possible to get the subset of a table which has a large number of columns.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto please suggest me if its possible using joins instead of the method I'm going with. thank you

Comment: Can you share the generated T-SQL and the expected one?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have updated the question with the idea of the query I'm expecting. PS I have to join 15-20 tables to get the result, it was taking forever to load 1000 records but i bought it down to 1 min using projections and adding indexes mention by sql profiler and tuning tools, still I'm not satisfied, most of the tables are 1-to-many relationship, and I'm totally a beginner at performance turning just trying out different methods

Comment: Sounds like you need a DBA more so than a developer. There are multiple ways to optimize databases (even many books around the subject), none of which correspond to what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto keeping the DBA part aside is it possible to achieve what I'm looking for in this question?

Comment: AFAIK, no, what you want to do might end up being less efficient than a join, given than a join can be optimized by the database server.

Comment: @Comraid what is `AsExpandable()`? There's no such LINQ method. For all we know this may be forcing client-side evaluation and loading 1M rows in memory only to produce 1000 by joining on the client side without benefit of indexing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos AsExpandable() is a method of LinqKit

Comment: Which isn't LINQ, can't be translated by EF Core and probably loads everything in memory. And as you wrote in a duplicate question, there are 20 tables involved, not 2

Comment: BTW LinqKit was built for EF 4.x, not EF Core. You should probably concentrate on writing a well-performing *SQL* query, with proper indexing. ORMs aren't meant for reporting or ETL jobs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Let Rephrase the question better and get back to you as you mentioned Will try to include the whole query. thanks for the clarification

Comment: This isn't a matter of phrasing. It's a matter of posting 20 table schemas and one full query that uses them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But LinqKit is available for .net core https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/

Comment: And that has nothing to do with the 20 tables in the real query. Without the actual tables, actual indexes, actual query, you're asking people to guess numbers for a lottery

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, you're right I just realized i couldn't be the only one who's facing the issue did some digging ended up with https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18022, this did address what i was looking for, will delete the questions as it was inappropriate to expect something else.

Comment: @Comraid you still don't realize you're misusing ORMs. This isn't a problem with EF Core.It's a design problem. I have big reporting queries with fat fact tables and dozens of dimension tables. I don't expose those in EF Core, because ORMs aren't meant for reporting queries. I create reporting views that abstract most of the query and map a *simplified model*. BTW that's what all reporting tools do too. I have to load several thousand rows every few minutes from very different files. I don't use an ORM for this, I use either ETL tools or code that reads and transforms the data as a stream

Comment: @Comraid to optimize a query with 20 tables you need to be able to manipulate that query directly. You *can't* have another tool interfering with what you do. What *does* the query look like? Does it include aggregations in subqueries? That's very bad because it forces the server to calculate those aggregations for every outer row. You need to be able to rewrite that query to avoid nested aggregations, or pass parameters to them to limit the scope of the aggregation

Comment: @Comraid what if you have hierarchical queries? You need a recursive CTE *BUT* in order to limit the rows scanned you need to pass filtering parameters to the CTE itself. Again, you don't want the ORM to interfere, or even know about the CTEs. And what happens if you move to `hierarchyid`? Why should the *application* be affected by this database-only change?

Comment: What if you find out you need to add some more indexes, change some joins or filters to optimize the big query? Why should the application have to be redeployed to allow this? This change is only relevant to the database, it shouldn't leak to the applications that use it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my original query looks exactly like the one it's mentioned in the github issue, the tables are normalized I mean it was working fine before, but recently we imported huge load of data, so it got me wondering if it was me doing something wrong in between we did upgrade to EFc 3.x. so i joined manually joining so get the SQL statements i would write on my own hence i landed with the above question!. Anyways i will upgrade to EFc 5 will see the difference may be or the workaround mentioned anyways will update you, once i clear it out!